# How to change zoom on TRIOPO TR950 Speedlite

Tags: canon, flash, zoom, hotshoe-flash

I recently bought a [Triopo TR950](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Triopo-TR-950-Flash-Speedlite-for-Canon-EOS-5D-Mark-ii-iii-6D-7D-50D-60D/32366648678.html) speedlite from [AliExpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Triopo-TR-950-Flash-Speedlite-for-Canon-EOS-5D-Mark-ii-iii-6D-7D-50D-60D/32366648678.html) which works great as a manual flash but I have one problem, I can't find any way to adjust the zoom on the camera. It has the zoom indicated on the LCD as 35mm but I don't know how to change it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't; it's fixed at 35mm.**

Looking around at several sources for the specs on the Triopo Tr-950 such as [the Cowboy Studios website](http://www.cowboystudio.com/product_p/tr-950.htm), [amazon.co.uk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/XDA-Triopo-TR-950-Speedlite-Universal/dp/B00JLISJQ4), and various eBay listings, they all say that the zoom of the flash is fixed at 35mm.

Comment: @tino1b2be Since this is SE, and not a messageboard, thanks can also take the form of upvoting or [accepting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer. :) If you plan to stick around, consider reading [the Tour](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tour).